# Troubleshooting Script to ping multiple remote servers with python

Tags: python, linux, loops, networking, ping

I wrote a brief python script to read through a text file containing multiple remote server IP addresses, I'm wanting to ping each address then print which IPs are not reachable and which are.

```
import subprocess
`import os
response = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '3'])
file = open('IPlist.txt', "r")
def check_IP_from_file(filename):
for lines in file:
ping_reply = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '3'])
if response == 0:
print lines, ping_reply
else: 
  print lines, "is down!
```

---

My output looks like:

```
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
[-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
[-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
[-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...]
destination
10.208.132.184 is down
```

It seems to only check the last IP on the List and Spits out a bunch of options for Ping's usage. in my script I do have Ping options defined. this is where I am very confused. I'm fairly new to python, so I'm okay with being called a noob, just please point me in the right direction.

Comment: You are executing ping incorrectly: it needs also the target host as last argument on `.call()`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Since The Host is multiple IP addresses in the "IPlist" text file. would I just call the List? for example: ['ping, '-c', '3', IPlists] ?     @GiacomoCatenazzi

Comment: probably `['ping, '-c', '3', lines.strip()]`, Not sure why you call `lines` at plural, and I do not know the format of the file. Eventually you should extract hostname (or IP).  Note: the first `subprocess.call` should probably go away

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer since I'm not 100% sure what you're going for but a few pointers for `subprocess`... use `Popen` instead of `call`, and make `stoud=subprocess.PIPE`.  Then `communicate` in the method addressed below.  That should help get you started.

```
import subprocess
import os
p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '3'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
response, errors = response.communicate()
file = open('IPlist.txt', "r")
def check_IP_from_file(filename):
    for lines in file:
        ping_reply_proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '3'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        ping_reply, ping_errors = subprocess.communicate()
        if response == <whatever>:
            print lines, ping_reply
        else: 
            print lines, "is down!
```